# Show that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial function locally then is polynomial in all $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and suposse that $f$ is polynomic locally, i.e, for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ exist $\delta>0$ so that in $]x-\delta, x+\delta[$, $f(x)=p(x)$ for some polynomial $p(x)$. Show that $f$ coincides with a polynomial for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Given one locale, can you show that the power series representation of $f$ (which is $p$) converges (and therefore agrees with $f$) on a larger locale?

Answer (score 2):

Your tag gives a hint: put it to be a complex polynomial in the strips $]x-\delta, x+\delta[\times\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and use "unique analytic continuation" theorem.